# react native android rf scanner broadcast

Tags: android, react-native, broadcast

I have a generic android based rf barcode scanner and am trying to capture barcode scans in react native.
Most every doc and library I can find uses the built-in camera which I do not want to use.
I also do not want to use the scanner as a keyboard, but rather use the broadcast mode.

Eventually I found `DeviceEventEmitter` however, have been unable to capture any event because I don't know the `tag` I need to listen for:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('someTagToListenFor', function (map) {
    console.log('Scanner content is: ' + map.referrer);
});
```

I have also tried to find a way to capture all events so I could pick one from the list once I pressed the hardware scan button without success. Is this possible?
How do I find the correct event tag to listen for?
Am I even on the right track with this at all?

The android device did not come with any documentation, but does have a demo app (no source code) that works with the broadcast model.

New to react-native so not sure where to go from here.

(note: this is not a zebra device so the zebra dataWedge stuff does not work)